# $(this) issue when defining a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to remove table rows on select. ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53XZU/42/))

```
$('select').change(function() {
     var $this = $(this),
            list = $('table tbody tr'),
            findoption = $this.find('option:selected'),
            selected = findoption.data('hide'),
            show_hide_li = $this.find("."+selected);

        if (selected == "reset") {
            list.show();
        }
        else  {
           $('.'+selected).show();
            list.not('.'+selected).hide()
        }   

});
```

When I move the code out of the `change function` and define it like the following, I have an issue with the $(this) that prevents the code from working. Can anyone tell me how to define a function when there is $(this) in the code?

```
var cancel = function(){
     var $this = $(this),
            list = $('table tbody tr'),
            findoption = $this.find('option:selected'),
            selected = findoption.data('hide'),
            show_hide_li = $this.find("."+selected);

        if (selected == "reset") {
            list.show();
        }
        else  {
           $('.'+selected).show();
            list.not('.'+selected).hide()
        }           
}


$('select').change(function() {
       cancel();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
function cancel(){
     var $this = $(this),
            list = $('table tbody tr'),
            findoption = $this.find('option:selected'),
            selected = findoption.data('hide'),
            show_hide_li = $this.find("."+selected);

        if (selected == "reset") {
            list.show();
        }
        else  {
           $('.'+selected).show();
            list.not('.'+selected).hide()
        }           
}


$('select').change(cancel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the "this" as a parameter to the function

```
var cancel = function(param1){
     var $this = $(param1),
            list = $('table tbody tr'),
            findoption = $this.find('option:selected'),
            selected = findoption.data('hide'),
                show_hide_li = $this.find("."+selected);

        if (selected == "reset") {
            list.show();
        }
        else  {
           $('.'+selected).show();
            list.not('.'+selected).hide()
        }           
}


$('select').change(function() {
       cancel(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.on` method of jquery

```
$('select').on('change', cancel);

var cancel = function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        list = $('table tbody tr'),
        findoption = $this.find('option:selected'),
        selected = findoption.data('hide'),
        show_hide_li = $this.find("."+selected);

        if (selected == "reset") {
            list.show();
        }
        else  {
            $('.'+selected).show();
            list.not('.'+selected).hide()
        }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This very brief, but powerful line, should replace the ones shown after:

```
$('select').change(cancel);
```

Replace below lines with above one:

```
$('select').change(function() {
       cancel();
});
```

Because these three lines are equivalent to:

```
$('select').change(function() {
       //you have access to 'this' here
       function() {
             //your body
       }
});
```

**And as you can see the inner function has no access to `this` unless you explicitly pass it as a parameter, which your can easily avoid by removing nested functions.**